# Why isn't my loop working? Only goes up to first print out

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out why my program is running? Can someone help steer me to the right direction?

```
import java.util.*; 

public class EasyLoops 
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Number:");
        int n = input.nextInt();

        while ( n > 0 );
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            n = n - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `;` in the while loop otherwise while loop terminates

```
while ( n > 0 );<- here
```

Comment: Wow you can really tell I'm a noob , I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` here:

```
while ( n > 0 );
```

That would mean the "content" of the loop is nothing,
and the `{}` after it are just for fun (valid, but needless)...

It would loop forever (if `n>0`) because nothing in n changes.

Answer (score 1):

Reomove the ";" the end of while statement. **";" is set only do while Loop not while Loop**

```
while (n > 0)
{
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    n = n - 1;

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
        while ( n > 0 );
```

Notice the semicolon. The syntax of a `while` loop is

```
while (condition) statement;
```

or

```
while (condition) { block }
```

You wrote the first syntax, and included no statement, so if `n` is greater than zero you will get an infinite loop (since `n` will never decrement).  If `n` is less than or equal to zero then the `while` will not execute and the block below will execute exactly once.

Answer (score 1):

you terminate your loop with ;

```
 while(n>0); // your mistake
{
  //your code 
}
```

try this

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Number:");
    int n = input.nextInt();
        while ( n > 0 )
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        n = n - 1;
    }
}
```